# uploading private apps to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I have developed an iOS app. The app is not a public app. That is, the user of app is me and my some friends. Now i need to upload the app into Appstore. I have a apple developer account.(it's cost was 99$). Is it possible to upload the app to Appstore using my individual developer account?

Comment: If you upload app on the AppStore then it will be visible for all the users. If you want to use your app for your organisation, then you need an Apple Enterprise account.

Comment: @Kuldeep Not that correct; the enterprise account may only be used within one single _company_, by and only by their employees.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen,  some specific users means users of 1 organization. Corrected the comment.

Comment: If the users are you and a few friends then you can use TestFlight. You will need to upload a new build every 90 days.  Apple won't generally approve an app that has a severely restricted audience.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit your app to your friends you have couple of options:

- **Option-1:** Set a login screen and custom username and password, then Publish
  it with your individual account to the `AppStore`. In this case everyone who knows the login details can access the features of the app.
- **Option-2:** Generate `Ad-Hoc provisioning` profile and deploy it to your friends
  (you can use `Crashlytics Beta` for free), downside is you need to
  register every devices you and your friends will use.
- **Option-3:** Use `Test flight`, down side is your build will expire in 90 days
  and you need to re-send a new build.
- **Option-4:** Get the `B2B / Enterprise license` and publish your app to anyone.